# Is the is_column in dm_sql_referenced_entities reliable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012, I've got a stored procedure that includes

```
INSERT INTO my_table_name(columns...)
SELECT ... stuff ...
```

but the output from `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('my_stored_procedure','OBJECT')` has is_updated = 0 for the one row where `referenced_entity_name = 'my_table_name'`.

What gives?

PS: I have run `sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule`, to no avail.

Comment: The data was updated, not the table itself.

Comment: @squillman So why is the is_updated column = 1 for a table that's updated in the stored procedure using `UPDATE my_other_table SET c1 = 42 WHERE c1 = 99`;